# SQL Server 2005 - Using CASE inside Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm using a select statement inside a stored procedure. All I need to do is based on the value of a parameter I've to use either RIGHT JOIN or INNER JOIN. Please anyone there help me to achieve this. Many Thanks in Advance..

```
SELECT FLD1, FLD2  
FROM TBL1 C (NOLOCK)    
     CASE
       WHEN @SHOW = 156 THEN INNER
       ELSE RIGHT JOIN TBL2 IC (NOLOCK) ON C.FLD3 = IC.FLD4   
     END
```

Is it correct? What would be the right way of doing this?

Comment: So your question is using case or joins?

Comment: I thought that I can achieve it using CASE. But I'm getting error.. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use IF statements:

```
DECLARE @Param VARCHAR(10)
SET @Param = 'RIGHT'

IF (@Param = 'RIGHT')
    SELECT t1.Something
    FROM Table1 t1
        RIGHT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE ...
ELSE IF (@Param = 'INNER')
    SELECT t1.Something
    FROM Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE ...
```

Or could be done as one SELECT (not necessarily best performance, be sure to test), something like:

```
SELECT t1.Something
FROM Table1 t1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE (@Param = 'RIGHT') OR (@Param = 'INNER' AND t1.ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres more than enough information on the case statement out there, [this should get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).